How can my package add files to the consumer's project?
I'm pretty sure in the past I have seen files added to my project when I add a nuget package reference. How is this done?
https://github.com/mrpmorris/Morris.AspNetCore.Authentication.Metamask.Blazor/tree/master/Source/Lib/Morris.AspNetCore.Authentication.Metamask.Blazor
I want the files in the Components and wwwroot files to be added to the consumer's project rather than being part of the class library.

I don't have time to give many details right now, but you might want to see whether what we do for the Google Cloud Functions Framework is useful to you: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dotnet/tree/main/src/Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting/targets

Basically we generate an entry point in the obj directory. I'm not sure whether that would be sufficient for you...

Thanks @JonSkeet - I'll try it as soon as I can get back to it!
